# What the C++ rules in regard to covariant return types?

Tags: c++

Like in the example below, what is allowed, how and why?

```
class Shape {
      public:
        //...
        virtual Shape *clone() const = 0; // Prototype
        //...
    };
    class Circle : public Shape {
      public:
        Circle *clone() const;
        //...
    };
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? If you know the term *covariant*, then you probably know what it means. So, the answer is: covariant return types are allowed. That's it.

Comment: Just one link for people not familiar with covariant return type:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type

Comment: Rule #1 of covariant returns - don't use VC6.

Comment: Please be more specific on your questions.

Comment: @Seth - What part of the question is unclear?

Comment: Simply asking "what is allowed" is about as unclear as you can possibly get.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++ Standard 2003. 10.3.5

> The return type of an overriding
>   function shall be either identical to
>   the return type of the overridden
>   function or **covariant** with the classes
>   of the functions.  If a function D::f
>   overrides a function B::f, the return
>   types of the functions are covariant
>   if they satisfy the following
>   criteria:
>
> —  both are pointers to classes or
>   references to classes
>
> —  the class in the return type of
>   B::f is the same class as the class in
>   the return type of D::f, or **is an
>   unambiguous and accessible direct or
>   indirect base class of the class in
>   the return type of D::f**
>
> —  both pointers or references have
>   the same cv-qualification and the
>   class type in the return type of D::f
>   has the same cv-qualification as or
>   less cv-qualification than the class
>   type in the return type of B::f.
>
> If the return type of D::f differs
>   from the return type of B::f, the
>   class type in the return type of D::f
>   shall be complete at the point of
>   declaration of D::f or shall be the
>   class type D.  When the overriding
>   function is called as the final
>   overrider of the overridden function,
>   its result is converted to the type
>   returned by the (statically chosen)
>   overridden function (5.2.2).

Example:

```
class B {};
class D : private B { friend class Derived; };
struct Base {
  virtual B*  vf4();
  virtual B*  vf5();
};
class A;
struct Derived : public Base {
  D* vf4();  // OK: returns pointer to derived class
  A* vf5();  // error: returns pointer to incomplete class
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Pff, too long standard quoting.

You can use another type as covariant if (a) it is a pointer/reference (b) it can be casted to the prior return type by mere addition of a constant known at compilation time (c) it is compliant to all constant-volatile qualifiers.

Comment: Maybe (b) would need some further clarification. It is not too common to define casts in terms of compilation time constants

Comment: For further clarification another post serves best